# Install python pip modules only for use by Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I am using Ansible from a pipeline agent, to configure Ubuntu VMs and I would like to use the [azure_rm_storageblob](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_storageblob_module.html) and [mssql_script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/mssql_script_module.html) module directly on the Ubuntu VM that I am configuring. I had some issues running this, because the packaging module was not installed on the hosts.

Is there a way to install the pip modules only for use when I run Ansible (maybe a virtual environment), as I don't want to mess with the pip modules that are installed on the server for other purposes.

If this is done using something like a python virtual env, how do I make sure that this is used when I connect to the VM using Ansible?

Comment: This is why we have virtual environments, to overcome the problem you are facing.

Comment: Do you have any guidance how this looks in an Ansible playbook?
I can create and activate the venv via the command line, but I can't seem to make it work within a playbook.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use virtual environments to solve that problem ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) to the python doc)

First you create the environment with :

```
python -m venv venv
```

Then depending on your OS, you have to activate you virtual environment, on Unix you can do :

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

The name of you virtual env should be written in your terminal, at that point you know you are using it and not the default python env.

Comment: You don't even have to activate the venv if you use the full path to executables (like the python wrapper as script) in the venv's bin directory. Activating mainly puts that bin dir on your path.

Comment: I was planning to use the [Ansible pip module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) to create the venv and install the required modules. However I don't understand how to switch to this venv during the playbook. I tried to run `. bin/activate` in a shell task, but that didn't work. My module that depended on the pip module still can't find the module.